# jSignature - How to redisplay image from DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have managed to save a captured signature to the data base, but it doesn't matter how I try to reload the image back into the jSignature it just doesn't display anything.
Any ideas help or examples would be appreciated.

Thanks Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exist a jquery pjugin for this:
http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/about/

And here a demo:
http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/demo/

If the problem is show the image, then you have to put a header.
  Example, image PNG:
  --> content-type: image/png

I hope this has helped.